# Pulseaudio complains about a lack of “org.bluez” and does not play any sound. How to fix?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth

My `pulseaudio` (5.0) on arch (Linux 3.17.2-1-ARCH) does not play any sound.

When running the daemon explicitly as `pulseaudio -vvvv --log-target=stderr`, I get the error message

```
GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172491, this is a problem with semi-installed (as in, not installed at all, but modules still exist) bluetooth support. If you deactivate bluetooth fully in your `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, by commenting out the following lines:

```
### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
#.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
#load-module module-bluetooth-policy
#.endif

#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover
#.endif
```